# How Do I save it to the database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

I'am Making a form which has checkboxes with values true or false.

```
<%= form_tag url_for(action: 'create'), method: "post" do %>
<tbody>
  <tr>
  <td class="image"> <%= image_tag("https://cdn.iris.nitk.ac.in/images/new_dashboard/button_Human.png", class: 'list_image') %></td>
  <td>Profile</td>
  <td><%= check_box_tag '1', true, true, :checked => true, data: {toggle: "toggle", on: "Yes", off: "No", onstyle: "success", offstyle: "danger"} %></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td class="image"> <%= image_tag("https://cdn.iris.nitk.ac.in/images/new_dashboard/withdraw.png", class: 'list_image') %></td>
  <td>Withdraw Admission</td>
  <td><%= check_box_tag '2', true, true, :checked => true, data: {toggle: "toggle", on: "Yes", off: "No", onstyle: "success", offstyle: "danger"} %></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td class="image"> <%= image_tag("https://cdn.iris.nitk.ac.in/images/new_dashboard/button_academics.png", class: 'list_image') %></td>
  <td>Course Registration</td>
  <td><%= check_box_tag '3', true, true, :checked => true, data: {toggle: "toggle", on: "Yes", off: "No", onstyle: "success", offstyle: "danger"} %></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

"btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block %>

upon submitting it takes me to this create action in controller.

```
def create
1.upto(13) do |i|
  (params[:i] ? (current_user.misc_data[:pin_modules] ||= []) << i : next)
end
redirect_to '/'
```

end
end

where pin_modules is an array that i want to create inside user model's misc_data hash.
i don't get any error while submitting but when i check db there's no array and nothing is saved.
Can anyone please help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're updating the objects attributes but as you say not saving them to the DB. Try:

```
def create
  current_user.misc_data[:pun_modules] ||= []

  (1..13).each do |i|
    next unless params[:i]
    current_user.misc_data[:pin_modules] << i
  end

  current_user.save
  redirect_to '/'
end
```

Or if you wanted to keep your ternary, just add a `current_user.save` before you redirect

Comment: apparently. it's giving undefined method 'save' for nil:NilClass error

Comment: That means `current_user` is nil

Comment: class CustomizeController < ApplicationController
    def create
    present_user=User.find(current_user.id)
    1.upto(13) do |i|
     (params[:i] ? (present_user.misc_data[:pin_modules] ||= []) << i : next)
    end
    present_user.save
    redirect_to '/'
  end
end

Comment: Then it must be failing validation... if you change `save` to `save!` you will see why you can't save it in the logs

Comment: Glad you got there :)